# Could not get device ID for smart card in reader ACS ACR122 0

Tags: acr122

I've tried multiple different RFID tags and cards with Windows 10 64bit Pro, but I always get this error in the device events:

```
Could not get device ID for smart card in reader ACS ACR122 0.
```

Installed this driver:
MSI Installer for PC/SC Driver (64-bit)  2 MB
Version 4.2.2.0
26-Jan-2017

Nothing seems to help, the reader doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, needed a **reboot** and configs for Smart Cards can be found here:

```
Windows + R: gpedit.msc
Local > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Smart Card
```